# CPU simulator time delay code

Tags: assembly, cpu

I cant find any info on this online, so any help would be appreciated.
I'm trying to incorporate some sample code involving time delays into a snake program we've been told to make by my college, which we are running in  "Microcontroller simulator".
Could someone please explain how this code works? I'll post it below:

```
; ---------------------------------------------------------------

;  A general purpose time delay procedure.

;  The delay is controlled by the value in AL.

;  When the procedure terminates, the CPU registers are
;  restored to the same values that were present before 
;  the procedure was called. Push, Pop, Pushf and Popf
;  are used to achieve this.  In this example one procedure 
;  is re-used three times.  This re-use is one of the main 
;  advantages of using procedures.

;------ The Main Program ----------------------------------------
Start:
    MOV AL,8    ; A short delay.
    CALL    30  ; Call the procedure at address [30]

    MOV AL,10   ; A middle sized delay.
    CALL    30  ; Call the procedure at address [30]

    MOV AL,20   ; A Longer delay.
    CALL    30  ; Call the procedure at address [30]

JMP Start   ; Jump back to the start.

; ----- Time Delay Procedure Stored At Address [30] -------------
    ORG 30  ; Generate machine code from address [30]

    PUSH    AL  ; Save AL on the stack.
    PUSHF       ; Save the CPU flags on the stack.
Rep:
    DEC AL  ; Subtract one from AL.
    JNZ REP ; Jump back to Rep if AL was not Zero.

    POPF        ; Restore the CPU flags from the stack.
    POP AL  ; Restore AL from the stack.

    RET     ; Return from the procedure.
; ---------------------------------------------------------------
    END
; ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you need any more information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the code responsible for the delay

```
; ----- Time Delay Procedure Stored At Address [30] -------------
    ORG 30  ; Generate machine code from address [30]

    PUSH    AL  ; Save AL on the stack.
    PUSHF       ; Save the CPU flags on the stack.
Rep:
    DEC AL  ; Subtract one from AL.
    JNZ REP ; Jump back to Rep if AL was not Zero.

    POPF        ; Restore the CPU flags from the stack.
    POP AL  ; Restore AL from the stack.

    RET     ; Return from the procedure.
```

The ORG 30 statement ensures that the code begins at the memory address 30.  This is the address you specify when calling the subroutine.

The code then pushes the AL register on the stack, because it is about to use it.  PUSHF saves the state of the CPU flags so that you can retrieve them later.

The DEC AL / JNZ REP section is a loop.  It iterates as many times as the number stored in AL.

POPF and POP AL restore the state of things before the code started the delay loop.  Specifically it leaves AL and the CPU flags in the same state the caller put them before calling this code.

RET returns control to the caller.

Now let's look at how this code is called

```
MOV AL,8    ; A short delay.
CALL    30  ; Call the procedure at address [30]
```

Specify a value of 8 for AL and call the delay routine, which you placed at memory address 30 with the `ORG 30` statement.

The delay procedure will loop 8 times, because you passed in a value of 8 in AL.